# Can't install a PECL extension

Tags: php, pear, operator-keyword, pecl

I'm trying to install a PECL extension called [operator](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator), which is yet in beta, using this command:

```
sudo pecl install operator-beta
```

It gets into installing the latest version 0.4.1 but after fails:

```
...
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJ71Qeg/operator-0.4.1/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/operator -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJ71Qeg/operator-0.4.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJ71Qeg/operator-0.4.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/operator -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c -o operator.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/operator -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJ71Qeg/operator-0.4.1/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootJ71Qeg/operator-0.4.1/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/operator -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/operator.o
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function 'php_operator_zval_ptr':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:76:11: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:78:32: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:82:31: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'CVs'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function 'php_operator_zval_ptr_ptr':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:138:11: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:142:31: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'CVs'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function 'php_operator_get_result_ptr':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:196:12: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function 'php_operator_set_result_ptr':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:215:4: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:216:4: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:216:57: error: 'zend_execute_data' has no member named 'Ts'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function '_php_operator_binary_assign_op':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:427:5: error: too few arguments to function 'object->value.obj.handlers->get_property_ptr_ptr'
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c: In function '_php_operator_unary_assign_obj_op':
/tmp/pear/temp/operator/operator.c:591:3: error: too few arguments to function 'obj->value.obj.handlers->get_property_ptr_ptr'
make: *** [operator.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: What's your PHP version? As far I can see, the **operator** extension is not  compatible with PHP 5.5 or newer.

Comment: @SlyChan were did you read about the incompatibility?

Comment: @SlyChan https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66752 From this page it looks like someone managed to install it with PHP 5.5.9

Comment: PECL changelog says nothing about PHP 5.5 support (only 5.3/5.4). The man, who reported bug, used sources from git repository, that is 4 month younger than PECL release.

Comment: @SlyChan If there's nothing can be done, thanks then